# Making a Standard ToDo List in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a standard ToDo List that reorganizes all inputted "New Routines" by numerical order of the HR value (reorganizing numerically based off of what hour the TASK is at).

It works, but if I list two items as having the same HR value (in this case both 'Go for a run' and 'Jump Rope' have an HR value of 06), it simply lists the first ('Go for a run') twice and omits the second item with the same HR value ('Jump Rope' is omitted entirely).

Any clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note, this is one of my very first attempts at coding in JS, for please forgive my current lack of knowledge as I am very much a noob.  And thanks in advance for any help.

My code as it stands is as follows:

```js
const currentRoutine = [];
let numHours = [];
let numMinutes = [];

function newRoutineItem(TASK, HR, MIN, AMPM) {
  let newObj = {
    TASK,
    HR,
    MIN,
    AMPM
  };
  numHours.push(HR);
  numMinutes.push(MIN);
  currentRoutine.push(newObj);
  return newObj;
}

newRoutineItem('Wake Up', 01, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Get Dressed', 02, 25, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Brush Teeth', 03, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Make Coffee', 04, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Make Breakfast', 05, 37, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Go For a Run', 06, 20, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Jump Rope', 06, 59, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Meditate', 07, 44, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Take Nap', 08, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Sledgehammer Time', 09, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Bicycle Around', 10, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Read Books', 11, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem('Make Some Art', 12, 37, 'AM');

function sortFirst(arr1, arr2) {
  var sortedObj;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[0] == arr2[i].HR) {
      sortedObj = { ...arr2[i]
      };
      arr1.push(arr1[0]);
      arr1.shift();
      break;
    }
  }
  return sortedObj;
}

function finalSort(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    console.log(sortFirst(arr1, arr2));
  }
}

let sortedHours = numHours.sort((a, b) => a - b);
let finalSortArr = finalSort(sortedHours, currentRoutine);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you able to edit your question with a clearer description of the expected behaviour and what the actual issue is.

Comment: Basically I simply want it so that when the code runs, it reorganizes the input by numerical order based off of what HR value is.  Right now it is doing that, but it will repeat a single TASK twice if it has the same HR value as another HR value, rather than returning both TASKs one after the other.  In this case it presents 'Go for a Run' twice instead of returning 'Go for a Run' followed or preceded by 'Jump Rope' which both have the the value of 06 in their HR property.  I'm somewhat confused as to why this is happening.  Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: All you need to accomplish this: "_reorganizes the input by numerical order based off of what HR value is_" is to do this: `currentRoutines.sort((a,b)=>a.HR > b.HR);` You don't need all of those other sort routines. If you want to eliminate some based upon some criteria - use `.filter()`

Comment: Randy Cadbury, I know it was obvious to you, but dang it I could kiss your anonymous face. You just made this insanely convoluted code work..eff. Thank you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick for you:

```js
function newRoutineItem(arr, TASK, HR, MIN, AMPM) { 
  arr.push( {TASK, TIME:new Date("2021-01-01 "+HR+":"+MIN+" "+AMPM) } ); 
}
const cr=[];

newRoutineItem(cr,'Wake Up', 01, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Tidy up', 02, 07, 'PM');      // this will become 14:07h ... 
newRoutineItem(cr,'Get Dressed', 02, 25, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Brush Teeth', 03, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Make Coffee', 04, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Make Breakfast', 05, 37, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Go For a Run', 06, 20, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Jump Rope', 06, 59, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Meditate', 07, 44, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Take Nap', 08, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Sledgehammer Time', 09, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Bicycle Around', 10, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Read Books', 11, 15, 'AM');
newRoutineItem(cr,'Make Some Art', 12, 37, 'PM');

console.log(cr.sort((a,b)=>a.TIME-b.TIME)
              .map(e=>(e.TIME.getHours()+":").padStart(3,"0")
                     +(e.TIME.getMinutes()+"h ").padStart(4,"0")+e.TASK))
```

Whenever possible you should try to store date and time information in a suitable `date`-type variable. Date and time comparisons are much easier then.

And please note that you *probably* meant to write `12:37 PM` since `12:37 AM` would be 37 minutes after midnight.

Comment: Thank you, this is a bit more extensive, utilizing the new Date object, and a method I haven't seen before, padStart.  Thank you, I'm obviously very new to coding and am very grateful for this.